# Did jest testing multiple files at one moment?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have problem with jest.
I have two files in **tests** folder and when I'm starting tests with them I have error about used port (listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000) but I'm closing server in both files in afterAll(). When I'm starting all test in one file (I moved tests from file B to file A) they are all passes. Did jest running multiple files at one time? I'm asking because I have read it should test file by file.

That work:

> File A only

```
describe("File A suite", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await dbConnection.create();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    server.close();
    await dbConnection.clear();
    await dbConnection.close();
  });
})
describe("File B suite", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await dbConnection.create();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    server.close();
    await dbConnection.clear();
    await dbConnection.close();
  });
})
```

That didn't work: (File A and File B)

> File A:

```
describe("File A suite", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await dbConnection.create();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    server.close();
    await dbConnection.clear();
    await dbConnection.close();
  });
})
```

> File B:

```
describe("File B suite", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await dbConnection.create();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    server.close();
    await dbConnection.clear();
    await dbConnection.close();
  });
})
```

Comment: Yes, it does, that's core feature. Can be disabled with runInBand option but not recommended

Comment: Thanks, so if it's not recommended I will try to write tests without that.

Comment: Make sure you don't operate on same tables/collections in different test suites, or do something to keep them isolated like mocked or in-memory db, there are numerous solutions for dbs for testing.